# Swift Creates a Protocol but it does not work

Tags: swift, protocols

I have Two Class One is **ViewController** and second is **UITableViewCell** 
IN tableview Cell I have created one Tapable link label . Label Delegates method to call my protocol method but its not working 
Here is my code 
1)**ViewController**

```
public protocol DataEnteredDelegate: class {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: NSString)
}

class ChatViewController: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() 
{

}
 func userDidEnterInformation(info: NSString) {
        print(info)
    }
}
```

2)**UITableViewCell**

```
class UIChatBubbleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,TapLabelDelegate
{
     var delegate_of_link:DataEnteredDelegate? = nil
 func tapLabel(tapLabel: TapLabel, didSelectLink link: String) {
        print(link)
         if (delegate_of_link  != nil) {
           delegate_of_link!.userDidEnterInformation(link)
        }
    }

}
```

Where I am doing a mistake if Protocol is not working then I have to use Notification Center 
Please, give me some solution.

Comment: provide sufficient code to properly address the issue. you must set `cell.delegate_of_link = <your_view_controller>` have you done that?

Comment: tapLabel this is another function not a cell function then how i get cell. delegate_of_link ,

Comment: In your second code snippet you have `delegate_of_link = nil` that should be assigned some valid value. I assume you are creating some `cell` in your view controller snippet 1. so there after creating a cell you must assign self to `delegate_of_link` so the method you defined in view controller gets called. Before doing that i suggest you check some tutorials on creating custom protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're implementing the delegate backwards. The UIViewController should be declaring itself the delegate of the cell, so that it responds to a call from the cell. So instead, it should look like this:

```
//TableViewCell
public protocol DataEnteredDelegate: class {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: NSString)
}
class UIChatBubbleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    internal var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate?
{

    func tapLabel(tapLabel: TapLabel, didSelectLink link: String) {
        print(link)
        self.delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(link)

    }

}

//UIViewController
class ChatViewController: UITableViewController, DataEnteredDelegate{

    override internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!UIChatBubbleTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func userDidEnterInformation(info: NSString) {
        //do thing
    }

}
```

Comment: This Code return a error 
cell.delegate_of_link = self 
Error is "Cannot assign value of type ChatviewControler to type Data EnteredDelegated?"

Comment: Make sure you declared that the Controller implements the delegate protocol, like this `class ChatViewController: UITableViewController, DataEnteredDelegate`

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind could you accept my answer? You can modify your delegate method to include the sender, and then use various methods to determine the sender. One of the easiest might be to set the cell's tag: `cell.tag = 1` and then check its tag to see which it came from.